# onclick function in android button with animation is not working

Tags: java, android, xml, animation

As I am new to the android I have written a code which consist of a button which has to animate and also link to another xml file. But when I compile it button will animate but it won't link to the other file. I need the animated button to go into the another xml page when I click on it.

code and image display are given below

button.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/bulbasaur"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >
<Button
android:id="@+id/enter"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
android:layout_marginBottom="58dp"
android:onClick="onEnterClicked"
android:text="@string/enter_button" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

/res/anim/anim_alpha.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator">
<alpha
   android:fromAlpha="1.0"
   android:toAlpha="0.1"
   android:duration="500"
   android:repeatCount="1"
   android:repeatMode="reverse" />
</set>
```

MainActivity.java

```
package com.coded.sandeep;
import com.coded.sandeep.SecondActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;
import android.widget.Button;
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
final Animation animAlpha2 = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.anim_alpha);

Button btnEnter = (Button)findViewById(R.id.enter);

btnEnter.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){

      @Override
      public void onClick(View arg1) {
       arg1.startAnimation(animAlpha2); //when i click the button animation is working 
                                          but onEnterClicked is not working can anyone 
                                                  help me to edit the code here such that both 
                                                  animation and link to another xml page works        
      }});  }
public void onEnterClicked(View view) 
{
    startActivity(new Intent(getApplication(),SecondActivity.class));
}
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
// Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
return true;  }}
```

Friends can anyone help me how to include both the onEnterclicked and animation such that the button will animate and then go to the other xml file were i have declared in secondActivity.java (declared in the program)

if I erase animation code above the onenterclicked function will work but both wont work I need both to be worked

Give solution to my problem I tried lots of things to both merge the code but it is not working sometimes I get errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove `android:onClick="onEnterClicked"` from the button in xml file

```
  btnEnter.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){

           @Override
              public void onClick(View arg1) {
               arg1.startAnimation(animAlpha2); 

Thread thread = new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // Block this thread for 2 seconds.
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(2000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                }

                // After sleep finished blocking, create a Runnable to run on
                // the UI Thread.
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                      startActivity(new Intent(getApplication(),SecondActivity.class)); 
                    }

                });
            }
        };

        // Don't forget to start the thread.
        thread.start();



              }}); 
 }
```

Comment: just give me 5 min i will check it and let u know about this @jyomin

Comment: ya @jyomin it really works thank you yaar hey one thing cant we do another type without using threads

Comment: as to show animation first and then start a intent so i think this is the best possible approach

Comment: ya thank you yaar should i do the same if i have 5 to 9 buttons @jyomin

Comment: create a new function with above code and call this on each button click

Comment: like again and again copying it for all the button 9 times correct

Comment: i am getting error near runOnUiThread it is telling to create a method and return null can u pls check it out

Comment: can u please post your logcat

Comment: k wait @jyomin and this is the error i am facing http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22961290/android-getting-error-near-runonuithread-when-i-use-it-near-fragment

Comment: 04-09 07:38:59.255: E/SoundPool(373): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
04-09 07:38:59.255: W/AudioService(373): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
04-09 07:38:59.665: I/Choreographer(1349): Skipped 83 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
04-09 07:38:59.735: I/Choreographer(1349): Skipped 44 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.@jyomin