# Android: getting error near runOnUiThread when i use it near fragment

Tags: java, android, xml, android-fragments

I am new to Android development and I want to link a button with the animation. I am getting error near `runOnUiThread()` and `getApplication()`. When I add this in as an activity it is fine, but when declared in `MainFragment` it gives error. However when I fix the errors, it creates a method and returns false.

```
public class MainFragment extends Fragment {


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, container, false);
    ImageButton btnFacebook = (ImageButton)rootView.findViewById(R.id.facebook2);
    final Animation alpha = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity(), R.anim.anim_alpha);

    btnFacebook.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            arg0.startAnimation(alpha);

            Thread thread = new Thread()
            {
                @Override               
                public void run()
                {
                    try
                    {
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                    }catch(InterruptedException e){                         
                    }
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                          startActivity(new Intent(getApplication(),FacebookActivity.class)); 
                        }

                    });
                }
            };


            thread.start();
          }}); 
    return rootView;
}}
```

In the XML file I only have the facebook imagebutton. When I click that, it has to trigger the animation and then onclick event has to happen, but I don't know why this error is popping up:

***The method runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){}) is undefined for the type new Thread(){}***

And near getapplication() method 
***The method getApplication() is undefined for the type new Runnable(){}***

If I create the two methods the error goes away, but then when I click onto the button it will not go to the facebookActivity.java file.

Can anyone tell/help what should I add to solve this issue. Thanks.

Comment: Take a look at the answer on this: [RunOnUIThread in fragment][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16425146/runonuithread-in-fragment

Answer (score 10):

`runOnUIThread(...)` is a method of `Activity`.

Therefore, use this:

```
getActivity().runOnUIThread(...);
```

But, beware. You're dealing with asynchronous threads, so your `Fragment` might be detached from its `Activity`, resulting in `getActivity()` returning `null`. You might want to add a check `if(isAdded())` or `if(getActivity() != null)` before executing.

Alternatively, use an `AsyncTask`, which handles this running on the ui thread by itself.

Comment: is it necessary to use checking up getActivity and AsyncTask can u explain little about this pls @Niek Haarman i am asking in depth because i changed the above code what u said now it is working fine will it lead to problem in future

Comment: can u please help to solve this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22986878/android-json-is-not-able-to-retrieve-any-files-from-mysql-database-it-is-empty?noredirect=1#comment35104130_22986878

Answer (score 2):

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){}) is method in Activity not in the Fragment.
```

so you need to change

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){})
```

into

```
getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){})
```

For your requrement it is better to use `Handler` instead of `Thread` for waiting 1000 milli seconds..

Comment: k i will check and let you know whether it is working @kalyan pvs

Comment: thank you @kalyan pvs i inserted an dummy file in my project and checked it and when i click it it is going to that dummy file

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22986878/android-json-is-not-able-to-retrieve-any-files-from-mysql-database-it-is-empty?noredirect=1#comment35104130_22986878 ....pls help me solve this @kalyan pvs

Answer (score 2):

Please use `getActivity()` instead of using `getApplication()` .

which returns the activity associated with a fragment.
The activity is a context.

Comment: ya sure but i haven't checked whether it works or not @Lavekush Agrawal